# How to manipulate multibyte string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-matching, multibyte, multibyte-characters

I have a log file having multibyte data in it (). I want to write a script that does some data manipulation on it.

```
with open(fo, encoding="cp1252") as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
        if("WINDOWS" in line):
            print(found)
```

print(line) give following output:
[image]

there is one extra byte after every character.
This is not working due to the fact that `WINDOWS` is not multibyte. I am unable to find the solution for this. Can someone help me here ?

Comment: `latin-1` is single-byte encoding, no?

Comment: it should be cp1252. sorry for the mistake

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: What is the error? post a full trace back and give sample data.

Comment: it doesn't give any error. Just simply doesn't match

Comment: If I open file with encoding = "UTF-16LE" then it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cp1252` is not a multibyte encoding. If the file in fact contains UTF-16, but most of it is in the very lowest range of Unicode, using `cp1252` will yield *roughly* the correct characters except there will be zero (null) bytes between them. Without an unambiguous sample of the bytes in the file, we can only speculate; but try opening the file with `encoding='utf-16le'`. (If this fails, please edit your question to indlude a hex dump or `repr()` of the binary bytes in the file; see also [Problematic questions about decoding errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors.))